# Embed js resource inside .cshtml page in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am looking at a sample application which is developed using ASP.NET MVC.

I see that they have embedded JS inside razor page. So if we expand razor page then we can see the JS file. How do we do that. I know how to do for web.config but not the razor page

[image].

Whenever I add a new razor page I cannot embed js inside razor.
Any help in this will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to figure it out..i specified dependent upon for the js file and now it got embedded inside razor page